# Running Simulink produces make error

Tags: matlab, clang, simulink

Opening a file in simulink and running it produces the following make error:

Making simulation target "ekf_trial_sfun", ...

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/bin/mex -c -O  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE    -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/stateflow/c/mex/include -I/Applications/MATLAB_R2013a_Student.app/stateflow/c/debugger/include   ekf_trial_sfun.c
xcodebuild: error: SDK "macosx10.7" cannot be located.
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH

mex: compile of ' "ekf_trial_sfun.c"' failed.

gmake: *** [ekf_trial_sfun.o] Error 1
```

I have clang on my computer. Do I need to open up the mex .sh file and rename all the old operating system refences (10.6) to 10.10.4? I tried doing a find and replace and that didn't work.
The file was given to me by another engineer 
I also get the warning: Some of the issues encountered during model compilation may be because this model was created in a previous release.

Comment: Do newer models compile fine?

Comment: You dont have the original simulik code before the compilation to c? that would be the straigtforward solution, to recompile it.

Comment: @Navan I don't have any newer version of matlab. Was that your question?

Comment: @Ander can you elaborate so I can understand what you mean? Thanks

Comment: I am guessing here. `ekf_trial_sfun.c` is code written by soeone or just generated by Matlab C compiler? If its the latter, then you can just recompile using mex

Comment: Ander, you were suspecting the issue could be because you created this model in a previous release. I was wondering whether a model created in your current release has the same issue or not.